# How to create variable in service angularjs

Tags: angularjs

This is my service code in angular.

```
'use strict';

sampleApp.factory('CommonService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var REST_SERVICE_BILL_PRODUCT_URI = 'api/v1/billproducts';
    //CommonService.Products = [];

    var factory = {
        getBillProducts: getBillProducts,
    };
    return factory;

    function getBillProducts() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(REST_SERVICE_BILL_PRODUCT_URI)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    //CommonService.Products = response.data;
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching bill products');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}]);
```

I want to add one variable in that and save response data in that. like this

```
 //CommonService.Products = response.data;
```

so i can use CommonService.Products in controller directly and access update it.

but defining //CommonService.Products = []; gives me error.

How to define a variable in service to use it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
CommonService.Products = response.data;
```

This statement won't work because `CommonService` is `undefined` at the given location, and context. Instead you may try this approach:

```
sampleApp.factory('CommonService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  // Store the reference of function's context here
  var self = this;

  // .. code truncated for brevity

  .then(function (response) {
    // Store response data into `Products`
    self.Products = response.data;
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
  }, function(errResponse) {

  // .. code truncated for brevity
```

Now you can inject `CommonService` in your other AngularJS components and easily use the `Products` like this:

```
sampleApp.controller("testController", ['CommonService', function(commonService) {
  // Access products here
  console.log(commonService.Products);
}];
```